# Problem sharing a library between WPF / Silverlight and GDI+ because of System.Windows.Point / System.Drawing.PointF difference

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, silverlight, gdi+

In the project I am currently working on http://sourcecodecloud.codeplex.com/ I have a library containing nontrivial geometry & layout algorithms. They are completely graphic engine independent.

The app was initially written for GDI+, now I am going to implement a Silverlight and/or WPF port of it. The problem is that all my algorithms use `System.Drawing.PointF`, `SizeF`, `RectangleF` structures. They are all `float` based. Corresponding WPF / Silverlight classes are `double`.

The question is, have anyone experience on that? What is the best way?

1. Create own wrappers for Size, Point, Rectangle etc. which can wrap both variants.
2. Stick either with System.Drawing or System.Windows and cast it in another. Negative impact is unneeded reference on the 'alien' assembly.
3. Some other magic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would begin with [Portable Library Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b0e0b5e9-e138-410b-ad10-00cb3caf4981) as your base. Any types in there are suitable for use across all your projects. For any types not present in there, I would create your own abstract types, and implement derived types which wrap the relevant type from each framework separately. Use the abstract types you create as much as possible from your own code.

Comment: Due to many thousand calculations I have doubts regarding conversion & casting. With this approach you have performance drawbacks on both ends, thus you should wrap and unwrap for both Win.Point and Draw.Point. Anyway thank you for advice - will look at the library.

Comment: This answer brought me in the direction which was mostly suitable for my application. I have created own structures and appropriate platform specific extension methods for conversion. Performance drawback was insignificant.

Answer (score 4):

One method that might be applicable is to use namespace aliases. You use an alias instead of the actual type and a compiler directive to switch between them. As namespace aliases are per file it might not be suitable if the code is spread over lots of files.

```
#if GDI
using Point=System.Drawing.Point;
#else
using Point=System.Windows.Point;
#endif
```

If you use `var` you can eliminate a lot of the checks, casts and keep the performance. You'll still need to look at functions that take and return specific types such as Math.Sin e.t.c.

Comment: Might not be an option for me, but anyway very interesting and pragmatic approach. Have not thought in this direction before. Could help anyone else. A bit tweaked around :D. +1.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the WPF types, and use some global (extension?) method to convert to GDI. They are more complete and more sensible than the Gdi ones. The downside is they are double based, so they are bigger. But with all that memory we have nowadays you are not likely to have a problem with that.

Comment: So you mean 2. I would accept your answer if no one will come up with a better idea. Memory is not really the problem, I am aware of issues with many thousands of conversions, which will occur during GDI+ paint operation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm developing a cartography/GIS application with a lot of geometry and graphics calculations. Initially I was using GDI+'s classes like `Point` and `PointF` directly in the rendering code, but it increasingly became a problem because I wanted to support Cairo, SVG, Direct2D and other graphics engines. So in the end I made my own interface-based hierarchy, like `IPointF2`, `IPointD2`, `IPointD3` etc. It certainly isn't perfect when it comes to performance, but I don't see a better way of keeping your algorithmic code separate from the graphics engine.

I [wrote something on this subject](http://igorbrejc.net/development/c/welcome-to-cairo) a while ago.